# Is there a single verb that means "to label items in a list with letters"?

Tags: word-request

What **SINGLE** verb means to list with LETTERS, such as the following?
I seek only 1  **SINGLE** verb; please exclude verb phrases, verbs containing > 1 word,
and 'to enumerate' itself (it's not precise enough; it can mean 'to number' with numerals or letters).

> a)
>   b)
>   c) ...

Comment: One supposes you're looking for a typographical term which refers to the labeling of items in a list not with numbers or with bullets but with letters? And letters only?  Not 1a) for example ? And is the parenthesis required?

Comment: I fixed the link in your question, which pointed to the synonyms for "detest", not enumerate. Where did you get the idea that enumerate (and its synonyms) was only used for numerals? is it because of the etymology? [Itemize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/itemize "to specify the items of; set down by items ") is a synonym for enumerate.

Comment: @ColleenV +1. Thank you for the correction! No; the etymology did NOT affect me. But I was seeking something more specific, because 'enumerate' can refer to both numerals and letters.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, you supposed rightly. Letters only; nothing combining numerals and letters like 1a). No; the parenthesis is NOT required.

Comment: Ah I see. You want something more precise than enumerate. From the way the question is phrased it seems like you are rejecting enumerate because it is too specific,  not too general.

Comment: @ColleenV Many thanks, as always, for clarifying my confusion. I just updated my OP.

Comment: There ain't no such word in English. You can always make some up and use hyphens to indicate a single word: *To letter-specify*. *To list-by-letter*.

Answer (score 3):

I would still use 'enumerate'. While it does contain the same root as 'number', what it actually means is ["to mention separately as if in counting; name one by one; specify, as in a list."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enumerate) It doesn't specify specifically a numbered list.

You could also just use 'list'.

Comment: +1 Why the downvote? This is in fact how *enumerate* is used.

Answer (score 0):

With no context, I don't know of a verb that distinguishes making a list of items with alphabetical labels from a list with numerical labels. The action is creating the list, so most verbs are distinguishing the method of listing not of labeling. How you label the list has so many possibilities that we typically use an adjective to describe the type of list we've created. For example, there are bullet lists, numbered lists, etc.

Some style guides might have names for different types of labeled lists. I'd have to do some research to find out and if you must have a verb, it wouldn't be useful to you.